# Win32::OLE creates a new instance when run under "GNU screen"

Tags: perl, cygwin, ole, gnu-screen

I am trying to access an OLE object "Broker.Application" via Win32::OLE

The application "Broker.exe" is already launched manually.

Running the following snippet from a bash shell using cygwin perl, it attaches to the running instance "Broker.exe" correctly

```
  $broker = Win32::OLE->new('Broker.Application') or die "Can't load Broker.Application";
```

But When I run this snippet from inside screen, it creates a new instance as shown below

```
$ ps -W | grep -i broker
     1912       0       0       1912    ?    0 01:07:37 C:\Program Files\AmiBroker\Broker.exe       #Manually started
     3896       0       0       3896    ?    0 14:39:41 C:\PROGRA~1\AMIBRO~1\Broker.exe             #created by Win32::OLE from inside screen
```

Tried Win32::OLE::GetActiveObject() but of no help as it returns undef even if an instance is running.

When tried logging into this machine remotely using SSH, that time also this script creates a new instance instead of attaching to the running instance.

Not sure what is making the difference between running this perl script from a stand-alone bash shell and from inside gnu screen.

Please suggest if there is any workaround to run it from inside screen.